# Can't to get the variance from submitting a from via post in CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't get the variance from submitting a form via post in CodeIgniter 2. As my below code, in my case I don't want to use the native form building in CodeIgniter...:

I have a form:

```
<form id="test" action="<?php echo base_url().login_form/test/;?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" style="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

I want to retrieve the testVal from my control, but it returns blank:

```
 class Login_form extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // Load required CodeIgniter libraries and helpers.
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function test(){

       echo "bla bla"; // I can see it on screen
       echo $this->input->post('testVal'); // I can't see it
       echo $_POST['testVal']; //Error: undefine the index testVal
    }
 }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

`action="<?=base_url('login_form/test')?>"` replace inside form action and try. Now you are posting to `login_form` controller, to the method `test`.
and you are missing `type="submit"` in the `<button>`

Comment: Can't get it . I chaned to action="<?php echo base_url('UM/login_form/login')?>" . UM is my subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with CodeIgniter form validation. Do not forget to add `type="submit"` in the button, which you have missed also. Please also make sure you have set your **routes.php and config.php**. You can add a custom route to route.php for your form, `$route['login_form/test'] = "account/login_form";`, etc. Please read the user guide.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Yours

`<button class="btn btn-danger" style="submit">Enter</button>`

> type="submit" missing

**Option 1**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form id="test" action="<?php echo base_url('login_form/test');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

**Option 2 with index.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form id="test" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/login_form/test');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

> In Controller: I have added a couple of validation methods, one using
>   CodeIgniter form validation and one using its own checks.

```
class Login_form extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // Load required CodeIgniter libraries and helpers.
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }


    public function test() {

        if (($this->input->server('RERQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            Run your success code

            echo $this->input->post('testVal');
            echo $_POST['testVal'];

            var_dump($_POST); // Checking testing

            exit; // Testing only. Check if the post is there.

            // redirect('whatpageyouwant'); Otherwise, use redirect.
        }

        // Load your view and data

        $this->load->view('folder/file');

        // Remember if have $data variable then $this->load->view('folder/file', $data);
    }

    public function validate() {
        // Custom Errors.
    }

    public function test123(){

        echo "bla bla";

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // Take your pick required or not required. Load your validation errors on your view read user guide.

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('testVal', 'testVal');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('testVal', 'testVal', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->load->view('folder/file');

            // Remember if having the $data variable then $this->load->view('folder/file', $data);

        }
        else {

            // Only should be able to see post after it has been submitted.

            echo $this->input->post('testVal');
            echo $_POST['testVal'];

            var_dump($_POST); // Checking testing

            exit; // Testing only. Check if the post is there.

            // redirect('whatpageyouwant'); otherwise, use redirect.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it, but the first condition always happen, mean that "form_validation->run() == false"

Comment: I have added another feature in there using server method with out coeigniter validation but you would have to set your own errors

Comment: Also all ways make sure you have set your routes so that the form action can work. and set your base url in config.php

Comment: in your button also need type="submit"

Answer (score 1):

In your form, replace

```
action="<?php echo base_url().login_form/test/;?>
```

with this one:

```
action="<?php echo base_url();?>login_form/test/"
```

It is because you are echoing your base_url first (e.g. localhost/sample_site/) and then appending the following 'login_form/test/'

Also, in your

```
 <input class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
 <button class="btn btn-danger" style="submit">Enter</button>
```

You have not assigned any 'type' attribute for your input with a name of **testVal**. I suggest you do this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
```

Then, your button is not assigned to 'type=submit' that is why the form is not submitting. It should be like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" role="button">Enter</button>
```

Last but not the least, you **NEED** to take into consideration CodeIgniter's [Form Validation Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

**Your code in your FORM should be :**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="testVal"/>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" role="button">Enter</button>
```

*Cheers!* *Happy coding.*

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer now after discover many things. The problem came from my htaccess file is messed with my controller. I commented out my htaccess file. Everything back to work again.

However, I still not understand clearly about it. But anyway, thank you very much, even you do not solve my problem.

```
    #<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    #RewriteEngine On
    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    #RewriteBase /Codeigniter/CodeigniterTemplate/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
    #RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]


    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    #</IfModule>

    #<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    #ErrorDocument 404 /Codeigniter/CodeigniterTemplate/index.php
    #</IfModule>
```